# Как получить текущий url адрес страницы и записать его в атрибут href?

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить текущий url адрес страницы и записать его в атрибут href? При это там уже есть какое-либо значение и мне нужно объединить их.

Пример:

До получения текущего адреса: `<a href="&FFF">`

После: `<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search&FFF">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
a.href = `${location.href}${a.getAttribute('href')}`;
```

```html
<a href="&FFF">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Тот код, что сверху, куда нужно записывать ?

Comment: Это уже зависит от структуры страницы. Обычно операции с элементами производят в скрипте, вставленном в конце тега `<body>`, чтобы они к тому времени уже были в документе. Или вешают обработчик события `'load'` на  `<body>` с функцией, тогда скрипт с этой функцией можно поместить и в `<head>`. Но это уже немного за границами вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

> window.location.href

Пример:

```
<script>
   function getURL() {
       alert("The URL of this page is: " + window.location.href);
   }
</script>
 
<button type="button" onclick="getURL();">Get Page URL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
copyLink(){ 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href) 
},
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]